# ERROR 1064 (42000) while creating a table and database in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

I am getting following error while executing my mysql query via a .sql script, but couldn't tell what is causing this error.

I am using mysql  Ver 8.0.23 for macos10.15 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near
> '/Users/shivamshekhar/Documents/Others/chat-app-backend/scripts/mysql/db.sql'
> at line 1

.sql file

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `chat_app`;  

USE `chat_app`;  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_details` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    `created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    `updated_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    INDEX `idx_name` (`name`), 
    CONSTRAINT `uc_name` UNIQUE (`name`)
);
```

Terminal command :

```sh
mysql -u admin -ppassword -e ~/Documents/Others/chat-app-backend/scripts/mysql/db.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-e` command means "execute the command", not "load and execute source file".

Send the source file to the client via stdin:

```
mysql -u admin -ppassword < ~/Documents/Others/chat-app-backend/scripts/mysql/db.sql
```

Or provide according command to the client:

```
mysql -u admin -ppassword -e "SOURCE ~/Documents/Others/chat-app-backend/scripts/mysql/db.sql"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Now my query is running successfully!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `INT UNSIGNED`, not `UNSIGNED INT`.  In addition, `NOT NULL` is redundant on a `PRIMARY KEY`.  So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_details` (
    `id`  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    `created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    `updated_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    INDEX `idx_name` (`name`), 
    CONSTRAINT `uc_name` UNIQUE (`name`)
);
```

Comment: I don't think there's an issue with my query. I have written INT UNSIGNED only.

Answer (score 0):

As already highlighted, it has to be int unsigned.
In case there is any partition column in the data base, that could be added at the end, specifying the compression type. (Depending upon the context)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_details` (
`id`  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
INDEX `idx_name` (`name`),
CONSTRAINT `uc_name` UNIQUE (`name`)
) partitioned by () stored as parquet  (compression =<"compression type">);

Comment: I don't think there's an issue with my query. I have written INT UNSIGNED only.